# FATAL exception, application stopped error

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

I am getting fatal exception error in logcat and application is stopping when run.

Java

```
package com.example.parth.editcal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static int a,b,x,t1,t2 ;
public static EditText tt ;
public static TextView ans ;




/* int p = { a , b ,x }
if (p[4] == 0 && p[5] == 0){

    p[1] = p[3];
    p[4] = 1;

}

else if(p[4] == 1 && p[5] ==0 ){

    p[1] = p[3];
    p[5] = 1;

}

if (p[4] == 1 && p[5] == 1){

    p[2] = p[3] ;
    p[1] = p[1] + p[2] ;
    p[5] = 2;
}

p[3] = 0 ;



*/
public static int logica(){

    if (t1 == 0 && t2 == 0){

        a = x;
        t1 = 1;

    }

    else if(t1 == 1 && t2 ==0 ){

        a = x;
        t2 = 1;

    }

    if (t1 == 1 && t2 == 1){

        b = x ;
        a = a + b ;
        t2 = 2 ;
    }
    x = 0;


    return a;
}

public static int logics(){

    if (t1 == 0 && t2 == 0){

        a = x;
        t1 = 1;

    }

    else if(t1 == 1 && t2 ==0 ){

        a = x;
        t2 = 1;

    }

    if (t1 == 1 && t2 == 1){

        b = x ;
        a = a - b ;
        t2 = 2 ;
    }

    x = 0;

    return a;
}


public static int logicm(){

    if (t1 == 0 && t2 == 0){

        a = x;
        t1 = 1;

    }

    else if(t1 == 1 && t2 ==0 ){

        a = x;
        t2 = 1;

    }

    if (t1 == 1 && t2 == 1){

        b = x ;
        a = a * b ;
        t2 = 2 ;
    }

    x = 0;

    return a;
}



public static int logicd(){

    if (t1 == 0 && t2 == 0){

        a = x;
        t1 = 1;

    }

    else if(t1 == 1 && t2 ==0 ){

        a = x;
        t2 = 1;

    }

    if (t1 == 1 && t2 == 1){

        b = x ;
        a = a / b ;
        t2 = 2 ;
    }

  x = 0;


    return a;
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    Button mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
    Button div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
    Button eq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eq);

    tt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tt);
    ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);

    if (x == 0){

        x = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString());

    }




    add.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){


                    logica();
                    x = 0;


                }
            }
    );




    sub.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                    logics();
                    x = 0;


                }
            }
    );



    mul.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    logicm();
                    x = 0;



                }
            }
    );





    div.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    logicd();
                    x = 0;


                }
            }
    );


    eq.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ans.setText(String.valueOf(a));


                }
            }
    );





















}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="42dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="x"
    android:id="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/div"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/div" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="/"
    android:id="@+id/div"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="="
    android:id="@+id/eq"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mul"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mul" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ans"
    android:id="@+id/ans"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eq"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eq" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.parth.editcal, PID: 17077 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parth.editcal/com.example.parth.editcal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2607) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.parth.editcal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:190) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5619) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2607) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 10-27 22:36:08.318 17077-17077/com.example.parth.editcal E/AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if your string is empty - otherwise you cannot parse an integer from it:

```
if (x == 0 && !tt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

    x = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the string value which you are parsing to int is not empty in the below line

```
 if (x == 0){
    if(null != tt.getText().toString() && !"".equals(tt.getText().toString().trim())){
         x = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now app is running. But getting ans =0 .Is there any problem in my logic